# Instabot Sending additional unwanted messages to users. How can I fix this error?

Tags: python, excel, automation, instagram

```
import os
# to delete config folder (throws error if not done)
if os.path.isfile("path/to/file/config"):
    os.remove("path/to/file/config")

from instabot import Bot
import pandas as pd
 
# Creating bot varible
bot = Bot()
 
# Login
bot.login(username="useername", password="password")
 
# Get list of users
user_list = pd.read_excel('data/UserList.xlsx')
users = user_list['Username']
names = user_list['Full Name']
 
# Message
text = "Test"

# Iterate through and send to every user on list of users
for i in range(len(users)):
 
    # Sending messages
    bot.send_messages(text, users[i])
    # print confirmation
    print("Message sent to " + names[i])
```

I am trying to use Instabot in the python program above to automatically send DMs to a list of users found from an excel file. I currently have 3 accounts list on the excel sheet but when running the script, instabot sends multiple additional messages to users who are not listed on the excel sheet.

```
2022-06-20 11:40:05,977 - INFO - Going to send 23 messages.
4%|████▋                                | 1/23 [00:01<00:32,  1.49s/it]  
4%|████▋                                | 1/23 [00:02<00:47,  2.15s/it]
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: So where is the list that the script is accessing as you say those names are not in the Excel list?

Comment: I have a data folder in my project folder that contains an excel spreadsheet with the list of usernames that I am trying to read from. There is not other list or data anywhere else that it can pull usernames from

Comment: forgot to tag you @SolarMike